# Overwrite specific class only in one buildType

Tags: android, gradle

In my app I have 3 BuildTypes: `Debug`, `Release` and `Internal`. I have one class `Networking`, this class is the same in Debug and Release but different in Internal.
 Can I create a project structure so that I do not have to duplicate the class in Debug and Release but only maintain two version: One Debug/Release and one that will overwrite this one when I build the Internal type? 
Sadly other project structure does not allow me to use productFlavors for this, so I have to use the buildTypes. 
TL;DR Is there a way to set a default Class for any build type and overwrite it in only one specific build type without having to copy the class in each build-type folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `buildConfigField` variable in your build.gradle, and set it to different values in each buildType. Something like:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_INTERNAL_CLASS", "false"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_INTERNAL_CLASS", "false"
        }
        internal {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_INTERNAL_CLASS", "true"
        }
}
```

You can then access that variable at runtime using `BuildConfig.USE_INTERNAL_CLASS`, and then do whatever you want, depending on whether it's `true` or `false`

Comment: That would mean I needed to implement and if in every constructor.

Comment: No, you would just make a single class, but inside it, you would change the logic based on the `BuildConfig.USE_INTERNAL_CLASS` variable